# Is bounded graph isomorphism $NP$ complete?

Tags: np, isomorphism-testing

Fix a matrix $M\in(\mathbb Z\backslash\{0\})^{n\times n}$ where $\|M\|_\infty\leq 2^{poly(n)}$.

Is the bounded graph isomorphism problem

> Given symmetric $A,B\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ and $U,V>0$ is there a permutation $P$ with 
>   $$PAP'=B$$
>   $$U<\sum_{i,j}(P_{ij}M_{ij})^2<V?$$

$\mathsf{NP}$-complete?

Comment: The question in the title isn't the question in the body, is it? The question in the title seems to be whether it is hard to solve the question in the body. Is that right?

Comment: One way to define boundedness is through what I gave.

Comment: Sorry, Brout, how does that comment engage with my questions?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Graph isomorphism can be translated to finding a certain permutation matrix, by looking at the graphs' adjacency matrices.

Comment: @Per, of course. But I'm glad to see OP understood what I was getting at, and made the appropriate edit.

Comment: the Frobenius norm of $P\otimes M$ seems to only depend on $M$ and $n$, not on $P$. Do you mean some other norm?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Sum of squares depends on pattern of $P$ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html. It is not Kronecker product https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices).

Comment: OK, I was confused by notation. In a less fancy one, it becomes $U^2<Tr(MP)<V^2$.

Comment: Well, assuming we take $M$ with nonnegative entries...

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Hadamard product is standard.

Comment: What might be standard in area might be very far from standard in another. As you don't need the resulting matix, but only the sum of its entries, it's notation bloat here.

Comment: It is not the notation alone per se.